# Providing params in AWS Glue interactive session

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I am trying to develop an AWS Glue job in pyspark using interactive sessions in AWS Glue. To use `job.init`, I have seen in [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) that the `JOB_NAME` is passed like so

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
...
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

a) When I run the notebook in the Glue Studio Editor, I get:
`GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: --JOB_NAME`. How do I set the parameter without running the whole job?

b) Ultimately, I want to develop in VS Code. Is there a way to set the JOB_NAME parameter there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Glue Interactive sessions notebook you can add required arguments manually by updating the sys.argv. See the example below:

```
sys.argv+=['--JOB_NAME', 'my_test_job']
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['JOB_NAME'])
print(args)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's actually what I ended up doing. Coming from a web-app development background, it's just odd to me that this is not in a file external to the code.